# Where to download Tracking Server 10 trial version?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, tracking-server

I need to learn tracking server 10. I couldn't find any download link to download trial version of tracking server. Where can i download tracking server 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same question was asked by someone else on the **[ArcGIS Discussion Forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/65240-ArcGIS-Tracking-Server-10)** 18 months ago and the advice offered there was:

> To get a trial version of Tracking Server, you will need to contact
>   your Account Manager, Regional Office or local Distributor (if you are
>   located outside of the US). If your organization happens to be in the
>   EDN (Esri Developer Network) program, then you already have access to
>   Tracking Server 10.1 and you can download it on your own.

However, it should be noted from the **[ArcGIS Tracking Server Community](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/tracking-server/)** page that:

> Version 10.1 was the last release of Tracking Server. At 10.2 a new
>   ArcGIS for Server extension called ArcGIS GeoEvent Processor was
>   released.

and that this is reinforced on the **[Tracking Server](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/tracking-server)** page where it says:

> With the release of ArcGIS 10.2, [ArcGIS GeoEvent Processor for Server](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisserver/extensions/geoevent-extension)
>   is replacing Tracking Server as Esri's primary server technology for
>   real-time GIS.